# Потерянный или затерянный?

Tags: стилистика

Половина новостных агенств сообщает: "NASA впервые с 2014 года вышла на связь с потерянным спутником". Другая половина: "NASA впервые с 2014 года вышло на связь с затерянным спутником". Как все-таки лучше: потерянный или затерянный? А NASA какого рода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С одной стороны, в толковых словарях Ушакова и Ефремовой указывается, что в разговорной речи "затерянный" и "потерянный", по сути, равнозначны.

Ушаков:

> ЗАТЕРЯННЫЙ — 1. прич. страд. прош. вр. от затерять (разг.). Затерянные вещи отыскались через полгода.
>
> ЗАТЕРЯТЬ — потерять неизвестно где, так что трудно найти

Ефремова:

> ЗАТЕРЯННЫЙ — такой, который потерян.

То есть "затерянный" — это либо просто "потерянный", либо "безнадёжно потерянный". Поэтому словосочетание "затерянный спутник" кажется мне возможным, если отбросить стилистическую окраску, которая тут не только "разг.", но еще и "ирон.", на мой взгляд, близко к "посеянному спутнику".

С другой стороны, чаще это слово употребляется в другом значении, особенно в литературе. Посмотрим значения в словарях Ушакова, Ожегова, Ефремовой соответственно:

> Забытый, переставший быть предметом внимания; одиноко-заброшенный.
>
> Забытый, одинокий, заброшенный.
>
> Забытый, всеми заброшенный и покинутый.

Если вкладывался такой смысл в слово, то словосочетание "затерянный спутник" уместно лишь в том случае, если его перестали искать, а потом неожиданно на него наткнулись вновь.

ДОВЕСОК

Что касается NASA, то, думаю, в таком виде можно употреблять в среднем роде, а вот при написании русскими буквами ("НАСА") уместнее в женском, потому что эта аббревиатура "читается", как МИД, например, который мужского рода, а не среднего, хотя "министерство".

Answer (score 2):

Не представляю, как можно говорить о "затерянном спутнике", кроме как в определенных контекстах. *Затерянный в глубинах Вселенной спутник...* – вот это было бы нормально. А здесь... НАСА потеряло свой спутник, вот он и потерянный.

Answer (score 1):

Прочитав о "затерянном" НАСА спутнике, можно сделать прямой вывод, что НАСА "*затеряло спутник*", что звучит крайне просторечно - несмотря на то, что слово "затерять" фиксируется словарями. Область употребления не та: в данном случае речь идёт не о затерявшемся где-то ножике и не о затерянных мирах Конан-Дойла, а о спутнике, с которым была "потеряна" и восстановлена связь (условно, говоря, "потерян" спутник - "мы его теряем" и т. д.), поэтому следует писать "**потерянный**". Что касается рода, с латинским наименованием лучше употребить (чем в уме держать) родовое понятие "агентство" (в прессе сложилось условное наименование "космическое агентство/ведомство" - независимо от вариантов прямого перевода) и с ним согласовывать: род **средний**.

Answer (score 0):

Национа́льное управле́ние по воздухопла́ванию и иссле́дованию косми́ческого простра́нства (англ. National Aeronautics and Space Administration, сокр. NASA).
Национальное **управление** -- средний род.

Потерять -- остаться без чего-либо, лишиться чего-либо вследствие пропажи, утери и т.п.
отт. Перестать видеть, знать расположение, местонахождение и т.п. кого-либо, чего-либо. Толковый словарь Ефремовой.

В приведённых Вами цитатах правильно -- **с потерянным спутником**.

ЗАТЕРЯННЫЙ, затерянная, затерянное; затерян, затеряна, затеряно. 1. Прич. страд. прош. вр. от затерять (**разг.**). Затерянные вещи отыскались через полгода. 2. только полн. формы. Забытый, переставший быть предметом внимания; одиноко - заброшенный. Исследователи отыскали два затерянных стихотворения поэта в старых журналах. Чувствовать себя затерянным, заброшенным. Увы, среди толпы затерянный певец, безвестен буду я для новых поколений. Пушкин.

Comment: А окончание -а говорит о женском. Кто знает об "управлении"? И главное, на хрена об этом знать?

Comment: Не уверен, что род определяется по переведенному названию. В таком случае НАТО должно быть женского рода (Организа́ция Североатланти́ческого догово́ра)

Comment: Понятно, что "с потерянным спутником" - это правильно. Но мой вопрос подразумевает сравнение с "затерянным спутником".

Comment: НАСА, как правило, произносят и пишут а среднем роде. Например: "Само НАСА каких-то опасных последствий от ноябрьской тьмы не ожидает".

Comment: Niemand привёл пример со словом "затерянный": Затерянный в глубинах Вселенной спутник...

Comment: NASA потеряло свой спутник, а не затеряло. Спутник потерянный, а не затерянный. Что тут мудрить-то?

Comment: @Матвей Дёмин, в словаре русским по белому написано, что "затерянный" — синоним слова "потерянный", причём в словаре Ефремовой пометки "разг." нет.

Comment: Ефремова не "луч света в тёмном царстве" среди составителей словарей.) Да и самому язык  надо чувствовать всё-таки. Почувствуйте фразу : NASA затеряла свой спутник. Хорошо звучит?

Comment: @Матвей Дёмин, так и Ушаков об этом говорит, и Малый академический словарь, но там обозначена стилистика. Есть и примеры, кстати: *Я получил ваши последние письма — более года тому назад, некоторые из них затерял и не отвечал вам* (Тургенев, Переписка), *Дай мне ключ от шкафа, я затерял свой* (Чехов, Три сестры). Фраза звучит приемлемо, но уж точно не нейтрально. Чувствуется насмешка (мол, вот как Маша-растеряша!), а может, даже намёк на то, что спутник был "затерян" целенаправленно, скрыт.

Comment: От нынешних СМИ таких стилистических тонкостей ждать не приходится. На нашем ТВ  не редкость  люди, неважно знающие родной язык.

Answer (score 0):

Потерять - потерянный. Затеряться - затерявшийся. Затерять - не употребляется в современном русском языке, поэтому затерянный не от чего образовать. Тем не менее, существует в некоторых устойчивых выражениях (затерянный остров) или в поэтических опусах для рифмы.
Например: нашли потерянный спутник; получен сигнал от затерявшегося спутника; Я будто затерянный спутник: то рядом с тобой, то в дали.